# Formulario de acceso a Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin

estoy tratando de hacer una web donde los usuarios que quieran acceder a un concurso deban registrarse en la web. Para ello he pensado en usar el plugin **cimy** que con él se pueden añadir campos en el registro de wordpress.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi intención es darle acceso a ciertas páginas a los usuarios registrados con el plugin **user access manager**.

Mi pregunta es: Cuando los usuarios se registran, pueden acceder al panel de administración de wordpress??? Porque yo solo quiero que puedan acceder a ciertas páginas de la web introduciendo su usuario y contraseña.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los usuarios de wordpress no podrán entrar en el panel de administración si son registrados por defecto como suscriptores, si se registran como otra categoría bien sea editor o administrador podrán acceder al panel, con modificar el rol sería suficiente, los grupos y el registro no deberían darte problemas si por defecto se registran como suscriptores.

Comment: Gracias, era la respuesta que estaba buscando !

Comment: Espero que hayas podido solucionarlo! :)